# Converting int to string with leading zeros in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

For example i have ints 12 and 7
I want to convert this numers to 5-char string with leading zeros, so 12 -> 00012, 7->00007.
It is possible to do it in postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I find the answer

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(7,'fm00000');
SELECT TO_CHAR(12,'fm00000');
```